# Commercial Component For Talking to Canon/Nikon Camera?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am currently doing some research on capturing images from an SLR camera, either Canon or Nikon branded from within a .NET WinForms application.

I know Canon and Nikon have SDK's but after reading around the net for a few hours I have come to the conclusion that integrating their SDK's is going to be a long and painful process.

My question: Does anyone know of any commercial (or free) .NET components for communicating with either Canon or Nikon cameras? I realise any component is just going to be a wrapper of the respective SDK, but we don't have the time nor resources to fiddle with C++ wrappers and everything that comes with that.

Any advice regarding this is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17344/A-wrapper-for-the-canon-CDSDK-and-PRSDK-for-remote

Comment: Thanks Josh, I had spotted that article, just going through the code now. Still hoping to find something slightly more complete, this project is from 2007 and I know Canon have discontinued their older SDK.                                                                   UPDATE: Both SDKS which the project implemented have been discontinued and won't support newer camera's.

Comment: WIA is the general Windows api for cameras and scanners.  It has a COM Automation interface, add a reference to c:\windows\system32\wiaaut.dll

Comment: Hans, we're looking for slightly more control than I believe WIA provides (zoom, flash etc..). As far as I can tell WIA only provides basic functionality.

Comment: Can you provide links to the respective SDK's and a list of the features that you want to use?

Comment: Access to the SDK's is restricted, both manufactures require you to complete an application process before they will give you access, I still can't understand why? I suspect this may have something to do with the lack of feedback regarding this matter.

Comment: just a thought, but if the integration looks long and painful for you, why not outsource it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [try](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/11/wpd-property-retrieval-in-c.aspx) the [WPD apis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/05/c-and-the-wpd-api.aspx) from [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2007/04/01/downloading-wpd-for-development.aspx).  Here is the [WPD Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/) for more information.

There is also a [Canon EOS framework](https://github.com/esskar/Canon.Eos.Framework) which claims to provide a better and more convenient way to integrate the [Canon EOS SDK](http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/) into .NET applications [Never tried, you may want to give it a shot].

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked the question [NikonCsWrapper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nikoncswrapper/) project became available, it is just a C# wrapper for Nikon SDK, but it integrates fine with .NET.

It is as good and reliable as Nikon SDK it uses.